# Insert variable into a specific cell in the HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, insert

I'm trying to make a program that calculates something and inserts the result into the cell next to the equasion in the table. I don't want to give each cell I want to insert the result in different classes because if I had to do this 1000 times then the code would get messy and I would have 1000 different IDs for each cell in the table. Is there a function that gets index or something of a cell and then I can insert the value into that cell? Or the only way to do it is to make these IDs?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: No, you don’t need IDs for everything. Familiarize yourself with the [DOM API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model).

Answer (score 1):

You can use relative addressing and a selector

```js
document.querySelectorAll("tr :nth-child(1)")
  .forEach(cell => cell.nextElementSibling.textContent = eval(cell.textContent))
```

```css
td:nth-child(1):after { content:":" }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>2+2</td><td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2*3</td><td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2-2</td><td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```